# issue with adding upload field to mautic form

Tags: mautic

I need to add a file upload custom type to my mautic form but I can't find the right way to do it. 
Is there a plugin to add or I must work with symfony to add it
Any suggestions please !

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to the file upload field feature is this PR: https://github.com/mautic/mautic/pull/3054

If you need it and you know PHP a little, you could help the author to finish it.

UPDATE: Form file upload was finished in PR https://github.com/mautic/mautic/pull/5082 and released in Mautic 2.11.0.